# Add seconds since Time '08:05' if timestamp is older

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this working SQL code (MySql), that returns number of Seconds a MState value have been eg. 4

```
SELECT SUM(Seconds_In_State) From 
(SELECT 
    Time_Stamp, 
    MState,
   (-1 * TIMESTAMPDIFF(Minute, LEAD(Time_Stamp) OVER(ORDER BY Time_Stamp), Time_Stamp))
AS Seconds_In_State
FROM Mstate
WHERE DATE(`Time_Stamp`) = CURDATE() 
AND TIME(`Time_Stamp`) >= '08:05'  /*ShiftStart input tag*/
ORDER BY Time_Stamp) AS T
Where MState = 4;
```

The result will not include the 300 seconds, where MState have been 4, from 08:05 to 08:10. Since I look at timestamps > 08:05. But I would like to include the time from 08:05 to 08:10 where the MState have been 4.

So it finds how many seconds from Time_Stamp where MState is 4, to next timestamp. From 08:05, and sums them together. If MState 4 have timestamp 08:00, it is not included. But I would like to include the seconds from 08:05 to 08:10, where MState is 4.
So if the MState prior to Time_Stamp >= 08:05, have value 4, add seconds from 08:05 to 08:10, to Seconds_In_State.

Data

```
|Time_Stamp              | MState |
|------------------------|------- |
|2021-04-23 07:50:00     |   3    |
|2021-04-23 08:00:00     |   4    |
|2021-04-23 08:10:00     |   1    |
|2021-04-23 08:22:00     |   2    |
|2021-04-23 08:30:00     |   3    |
|2021-04-23 08:40:00     |   4    |
|2021-04-23 08:50:00     |   1    |
|2021-04-23 09:01:00     |   2    |
|2021-04-23 09:10:00     |   3    |
```

Result from current code:
|SUM(Seconds_In_State) |
|600                   |

Result I would like to get:

|SUM(Seconds_In_State) |
|900                   |

Comment: Can you include your expected result that you expect to get based on your sample data, and the result you actually get?

Comment: I have just updated the question, hopefully to be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want `lag()` and a comparison to enforce the timeframe:

```
SELECT SUM(Seconds_In_State) 
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(Minute, 
                           GREATEST(LAG(Time_Stamp) OVER (ORDER BY Time_Stamp), addtime(cast(curdate() as datetime), '08:05')), 
                           Time_Stamp
                          ) AS Seconds_In_State
      FROM Mstate s
      WHERE DATE(Time_Stamp) = CURDATE() AND
            TIME(Time_Stamp) >= '08:05'  /*ShiftStart input tag*/
     ) s
WHERE MState = 4
ORDER BY Time_Stamp
```

Comment: the s.* gives me a syntax error. I do not know the s.* "function"

Comment: put comma beside s.*,

Comment: It returned NULL as result

Comment: The comma solved the syntax error, thanks. I just updated the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Still I did not understand your question. Could you pls display output column you want?

Comment: I think LEAD is the right function, since I want the time the value is 4.

Comment: Sorry, it is a bit difficult to write the question so it is clear. 
I have given is a new try.